# I have a trouble when i try to read a .txt file in java

Tags: java, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to read a `.txt` file, but when I debug the file, NetBeans shows me a class called `EventDispatchThread.java` and star this while:

```
void pumpEventsForFilter(int id, Conditional cond, EventFilter filter) {
    addEventFilter(filter);
    doDispatch = true;
    while (doDispatch && !isInterrupted() && cond.evaluate()) {
        pumpOneEventForFilters(id);
    }
    removeEventFilter(filter);
}
```

I don't know why; I will show my code below and I hope you can tell what I'm doing wrong.

```
private void btnCrearRutinaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String Musculos = null;
    String Brazo, Pecho, Hombro, Espalda, Pierna, Abdomen, Cardio, Tiempo;
    Object NivelEjercicio = CmbNivel.getSelectedItem();
    String NE = String.valueOf(NivelEjercicio);
    Tiempo = txtTiempo.getText();

    if (checkBrazo.isSelected()) {
        Brazo = "Brazo";
        ArrayList RutinaFinal;
        String Archivo = "C:\\Users\\luisricardo\\Documents\\Brazo.txt";
        try {
            RutinaFinal = Rutina.buscarEjercicios(Archivo, 30);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MenuCreateRutnia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors???

Comment: Every action that starts from a UI component will run in the Event Dispatch Thread. Since this action starts from a button press (I assume), it will run on the EDT. You should take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html. The fact that it runs on EDT doesn't influence the file reading but it is not recommended to do long actions on the EDT since the UI will be unresponsive.